# Response interceptor in node js using npm rocky

Tags: node.js, npm

I have rest api service already with me from one of software, I dont want to call this API directly so I have added a proxy to it, using NPM module Rocky, i am able to forward my request to MY API SERVICE, but in the response i have to pass few more parameters(i.e to manipulate my response), 
below is the code snippet i am using.

```
JS

proxy
  .post('/Authenticate/user')
  .forward('http://192.168.1.200:8081/v1/')
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    if(req.params.name === 'admin') {
      // Overwrite the target URL only for this user
        console.log('Intercepted log');
    }
    next();
  });
```

But i am not able to intercept it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help -

```
proxy
  .post('/Authenticate/user')
  .forward('http://192.168.1.200:8081/v1/')
  .use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.name === 'admin') {
      // Overwrite the target URL only for this user 
      console.log('Intercepted log');
      // manipulate res here
    }
    next();
  });
```

Comment: call is Not coming in .use block {}